# Can someone help me separate a log file into a separate file for each hour & day?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want a script to extract logs from a file xyz.rawlog, then create a xyz directory full of files named:

```
Arp-14-00.rawlog
Apr-14-01.rawlog
Full example: 
~/xyz/Apr-14-02.rawlog
```

One possible issue: Log lines may have the leading 0 in the day field, or it may be spaced out.

```
Example:
Apr 01 12:
Apr  1 12:
```

Sample Logs:

```
Apr 14 02:35:33 DC501.xx.org/10.1.7.145/1.13.136.2 MSWinEventLog,4,Security,3959142,Tue Apr 14 02:35:32 2015,4769,Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing,XX.ORG\PereyrR1@XX.ORG,N/A,Success Audit,DC501.xx.org,Kerberos Service Ticket Operations,,A Kerberos service ticket was requested. Account Information: Account Name: PereyrR1@XX.ORG Account Domain: XX.ORG Logon GUID: {2F6FCDED-FBA0-DBF5-88D2-0B048E612E21} Service Information: Service Name: AHCTXXML501$ Service ID: ... –  Joshua C. 44 mins ago  

Apr 14 04:32:16 1232-devr01/127.0.0.1/1.14.0.65 kernel: iptables:IN= OUT=upstream1 SRC=2.7.1.238 DST=207.188.35.17 EN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2574 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34030 DPT=61613 WINDOW=112 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 –
```

This is how I want the command syntax.

```
 ~/Logsplit.sh xyz
```

Working Script:

```
#/bin/bash
mkdir $1
awk -v fpath="$1" -F":" '{ 
    filename = fpath "/" gensub("[ ]+", "-", "g", $1) ".rawlog"; 
    print >> filename
}' $1.rawlog

exit;
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the contents of the log file?

Comment: There are a variety of log types, but the date field is always out front. Below are sample Windows and Unix logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did understand correctly your question, you want to split content by date, where the full line of content is to be inserted in that new file. 
You can do something like:

`

```
mkdir $1
awk -v fpath="$1" -F":" '{ 
    filename = fpath "/" gensub("[ ]+", "-", "g", $1) ".rawlog"; 
    print >> filename
}' $1.rawlog
```

`

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
awk -F: '{split($1,a," ");print $1 > a[1]"_"a[2]+0"_"a[3]+0".log"}' *.rawlog
```